Error in QGIS when translate rasters and using the clip raster by a mask layer tool
I have been working on 2 separate projects with raster data. For one I have been trying to clip the raster by a masking layer and the other one I have been trying to convert/translate the data. For both I keep getting the same error messages. One about the GDAL command and the other about loading data was unsuccessful.
I have tried saving the data as both a temporary scratch layer and to a few different places on my computer.
Does anyone know whats going on? It seems like it may be that the system is having a hard time finding a pathway to save the data or something.
GDAL command:
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0.0 -of GTiff "/Users/me/Documents/UPS/ENVS 250 GIS/PierceCountySeaLevelRise/Below Sea Level 3.8" /private/var/folders/zs/4m99_wgd3ll8c_h5yb6w0kbm0000gn/T/processing_YdcVHI/c2648a20455d4e6b883482a62b1e5cca/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
/Applications/Lab Tools/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdal_translate: line 3: /Applications/Lab: No such file or directory
Process returned error code 127
Execution completed in 0.09 seconds
Results:
  OUTPUT: /private/var/folders/zs/4m99_wgd3ll8c_h5yb6w0kbm0000gn/T/processing_YdcVHI/c2648a20455d4e6b883482a62b1e5cca/OUTPUT.tif


Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /private/var/folders/zs/4m99_wgd3ll8c_h5yb6w0kbm0000gn/T/processing_YdcVHI/c2648a20455d4e6b883482a62b1e5cca/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.


Maybe it has a hard time finding the source? Try to remove spaces and point from "...Below Sea Level 3.8".

It looks like a problem locating GDAL_Translate, there's a space in the file name. I suggest you uninstall QGIS and reinstall it to a location that does not have spaces in the file path.

You could try to use the "Georeferencer Extension" plugin to clip your image into a VRT file: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeorefExtension/
